# How can I play 60fps videos?

Tags: video, camera, codecs

I have a Contour camera, which is a sports/action camera and records at 60 fps.

When I load any video in Ubuntu using any video player, lots of frames are lost. I tried changing codecs but nothing improved...

Does Ubuntu support 60 FPS videos? If so, how can I play them?

Comment: Have you tried installing the proprietary GPU drivers? Or maybe your CPU is too slow to render 60 FPS videos fast enough (but I doubt it). What are your computer specs?

Comment: Most likely a basic performance issue. I've just converted a video to 60 fps running at 720 resolution - certainly no problems here. Flicker free, smooth, etc. All done with a dual core and a nVidia GT210.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar experience times ago (was on 11.10 box).
Simply try to install vlc player, I think it's the best player on linux you can found.